# Search in Array and Return value using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, lookup

I have an array in VBA that has a string of characters. I need to use lookup function from the Array cells such that whenever the value is found, the corresponding cells in the row get copied to a different Sheet.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim process() As Variant

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set hc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hourly Cuts")
Set ds = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Downtime Summary")
Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary")

ds.Activate

process = Range("V2", Selection.End(xlDown))
a = sh.Range("R1")

For i = 1 To a
    If ds.Range("F", i + 3) = process Then Summary.Range("B", i + 6) = 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

How do I use the lookup function using vba?

Comment: `How do I use the lookup function using vba?` look at Range.Find() method.  Or use Appliction.Match().

Comment: How do I refer to the array using Application.Match() function?

Comment: Application.Match(*Value to find*,ds.Range("F:F"),0).  Which return a Long equal to the row in which the first value was found.  Or it will return an error if it is not found.

Comment: Sorry for silly questions.. I am a beginner at VBA.. On writing the code -         b = Application.Match(process, ds.Range("F", j), 0) I am getting the message "Application-defined or object-finding error"... Here process is my Array and I need to find in column F (iteratively) if the value in each cell is a part of the array...